# Without using a calculator and logarithm, which of $100^{101} , 101^{100}$ is greater?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality, approximation, upper-lower-bounds, number-comparison

Which of the following numbers is greater? Without using a calculator and logarithm.

$$100^{101} , 101^{100}$$

My try :  $$100=10^2\\101=(100+1)=(10^2+1)$$

So  :

$$100^{101}=10^{2(101)}\\101^{100}=(10^2+1)^{100}=10^{2(100)}+N$$

Now what ?

Comment: Hint:  the function $x^{1/x}$ is decreasing for $x>e$.

Comment: A special case of https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/517555/fastest-way-to-check-if-xy-yx/

Comment: @lulu: as is $\dfrac{\log x}{x}$

Comment: @Henry  right, same thing.

Comment: These boundary methods are usually employed in Computing Science.

Comment: Maybe use a proper title, with some information about the question?

Comment: @Dehbop Please don't post answers as comments.

Comment: Basic logic dictates that power wins vs multiplication in any x > e .

Comment: Questions like this have been asked here like hundred of times. Among those answers are many proofs satysfying your criteria. [Prove $n^{n+1}$ is greater than $(n+1)^n$ for all $n > 2$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/976111/prove-nn1-is-greater-than-n1n-for-all-n-2), [Which of the numbers $99^{100}$ and $100^{99}$ is the larger one?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/103431/which-of-the-numbers-99100-and-10099-is-the-larger-one), [Which is larger, $70^{71}$ or $71^{70}$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1824314/which-is-larger-7071-or-7170)

Comment: [Showing that for $n\geq 3$ the inequality $(n+1)^n<n^{(n+1)}$ holds](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1612256/showing-that-for-n-geq-3-the-inequality-n1nnn1-holds), [Prove that $n^{(n+1)} > (n+1)^{n}$ when $n\geq 3$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1424277/prove-that-nn1-n1n-when-n-geq-3). I am buffled why none of the 3,152 people checking this in last 9 days have noticed it (or they did but thought reposting existing answer is better idea?)

Answer (score 55):

You want to determine if $\left(\frac{101}{100}\right)^{100}\geq 100$. But we know that $ \left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^n$ is always less than $e$.

Comment: This is the nicest solution. I love it

Answer (score 40):

101<sup>100</sup> = (100+1)<sup>100</sup>

Using the binomial theorem, we get 101 terms, none of them greater than 100<sup>100</sup>, and the three smallest of these terms add up to less than 100<sup>100</sup>. So the sum is less than 99(100<sup>100</sup>), which is less than 100(100<sup>100</sup>), which is equal to  100<sup>101</sup>.

Comment: This the only answer that doesn't require knowledge of $e$.

Answer (score 25):

$$\frac{101^{100}}{100^{101}} =\frac1{100}\cdot \left(\frac{101}{100}\right)^{100}=\frac1{100}\cdot\left(1+\frac1{100}\right)^{100}\approx \frac e{100}\ll 1$$

Of course, the "$\approx$" needs to be tamed, but the "$\ll$" allows for much leeway. One way to elaborate the idea is to use 
$$ \left(1+\frac1{100}\right)^{100}\cdot \left(1-\frac1{100}\right)^{100}=\left(1-\frac1{10000}\right)^{100}<1$$
and Bernoulli's inequality: 
$$\left(1-\frac1{100}\right)^{100}=\left(1-\frac1{100}\right)^{50}\cdot \left(1-\frac1{100}\right)^{50}\ge \left(1-\frac{50}{100}\right)^2=\frac14$$
so that ultimately 
$$\frac{101^{100}}{100^{101}}<\frac 4{100}. $$

Comment: Didn't you meant $\frac{1}{100}$ as first term after first equality?

Comment: About taming the approximation, doesn't $(1+1/n)^n = e'$  approach $e$ from below, so that $e' < e$ always? And then $e'/100 < 1$

Comment: I don't see what good is multiplying $\left(1+\frac1{100}\right)^{100}$ with $\left(1-\frac1{100}\right)^{100}$, arrive at $\left(1-\frac1{10000}\right)^{100}$???

Answer (score 6):

In [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/306245), it is shown that $\left(1+\frac1n\right)^n$ increases to $e\lt3$. Thus, for $n\ge3$,
$$
\left(1+\frac1n\right)^n\lt n
$$
Multiply by $n^n$ and we get
$$
(n+1)^n\lt n^{n+1}
$$

Answer (score 1):

for a sequence, $100^n$, as n increases, the number of digits increases by 2.

In the sequence of $101^n$, after finding the first 3 terms one can see the pattern and conclude that for all values of n, the term is 2 digits more than the last term, never 3 digits more. $101, 10201, 1030301, 104040401, 10505050501\dotsc$

If we compare $100^{101}$ and $101^{100}$, we can use the two above observations to conclude that $100^n > 101^{n-1}$, so $100^{101} > 101^{100}$.

Comment: I'm not convinced by your argument about the number of digits in $101^n$.  Consider, for example, $101^{231}$ vs $101^{232}$.  Indeed, we know that your argument eventually fails, because $101^n \gg 100^n$ when $n$ is very large.

Comment: 101^n is always larger than 100^n unless n is 0, so what you said is correct but doesn't dispute what I stated, ill keep looking at larger scales though

Comment: the sequence can be written using recursion as A(n)=A(n-1)+A(n-1)*100. in the case you mentioned, 101^232 would be equal to 101^231+101^231*100. These differ by 2 units. This means that 101^231<100^232 (sorry I'm new to using a computer to write math so I don't know how to make it display the correct notation)

Comment: looking at the sequence of $101^n$ what I see is that it starts with 100+n as the first digits. This suggests to me that if n is over 1000 that it will add more digits. That n is bigger than this current case but it means that your "never 3 digits more" is provably wrong and thus needs to be better specifed. In fact I believe this can be seen more easily by considering that the number of digits in a number is one more than the integer part of the base 10 log of that number. In this case that would be $n*log(101)$ which goes up by three from 231 to 232 (as Xander implied above).