# A really basic inequality

Tags: inequality

Prove that $5^{44}<4^{53}$

I tried to prove that $5^{44}<4^{52}$

$\implies 5^{11}<4^{13}$

But couldn't

Comment: The two numbers aren't particularly close...as a hint, use $2^7>5^3$.

Comment: Thanks now I got it. How did you find the solution.

Comment: Like how you approached it,

Comment: Since $2^7$ is just a little greater than $2^5$ I figured it was likely that we could use those numbers as a base.  Can't really be sure till you write it out, of course.  Worth noting that the same calculation actually shows that $2^{103}>5^{44}$.

Comment: This is an abstract duplicate of [Without using a calculator and logarithm, which of $100^{101} , 101^{100}$ is greater?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2540063/without-using-a-calculator-and-logarithm-which-of-100101-101100-is-gr). Same problem, different numbers. Found using Approach0.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that
$
4^{53} = 2^{106} ,
$
so you need to show that $$2^{106} > 5^{44} \; . $$

Now try to find a *simpler* inequality of that form $2^x > 5^y$:
$$
2^7 = 128 > 125 = 5^3
$$
Now we can use this to prove the original inequality:
$$
2^{106} = 2 \cdot 2^{105} = 2 \cdot \left( 2^7 \right)^{15} > 2 \cdot \left( 5^3 \right)^{15} = 2 \cdot 5^{45} > 5^{45} > 5^{44} \; .
$$

Comment: Thanks bro, was looking for this

Comment: Still a typo in that ( ), you want $5^3$, not $2^3$.